# Server API Versioning with Service Workers

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, backend, service-worker

I've been working with Angular Service Workers, and one area I've been struggling to understand is how to prevent an old application bundle (has not been reloaded yet), from getting faulty responses due to accessing newer server APIs. Do all breaking changes (non-backwards compatible) to server endpoints need to be versioned? What is best-practice in this area?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you need to manage the versioning yourself. A couple of possibilities:

- Anytime your API changes you change the endpoint in your client side code. This will change the hash of the stored file, then you can detect that with the window['isUpdateAvailable'] and show the user that an update is required to match your newest API version.

More info here: [PWA Update Available](https://medium.com/progressive-web-apps/pwa-create-a-new-update-available-notification-using-service-workers-18be9168d717)

- You can cache all the old API responses and serve those even when an update is available. Then your outdated requests will still get valid info even if your API changes. If the user reloads they will receive the new application bundle with the new endpoints.

These solutions depend on what kind of data you are serving. If it always needs to be up to date then you should handle versioning. If it can be out of date you could serve from a cache.